# Polyfill for push method in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

In recent interview, interviewer has asked can you write polyfill for `push()` method in javascript.

any one know how to do this .?

Answer (score 2):

[`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) adds one or more elements at the end of `array` and returns new `length` of array. You can use array's `length` property to add element at the end of it.

```
if (!Array.prototype.push) {
// Check if not already supported, then only add. No need to check this when you want to Override the method

    // Add method to prototype of array, so that can be directly called on array
    Array.prototype.push = function() {

        // Use loop for multiple/any no. of elements
        for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            this[this.length] = arguments[i];
        }


        // Return new length of the array
        return this.length;
    };
}
```

Comment: You also need to update `this.length` to make `Array.prototype.push` generic. So somewhere add `this.length = Number(this.length) || 0;` and `this.length += 1`.

Comment: @KingMob I don't think that is needed. As if you have empty array, it's length will be always zero, no need to set this. And `this.length += 1` is not needed, as you're adding new elements in array, `length` will be automatically incremented by one, for each addition

Comment: I mean for `Array.prototype.push.call` on, e.g. `{length: 0}`.

Answer (score 1):

```js
if (!Array.prototype.push) {
  Array.prototype.push = function () {
    for (var i = 0, len = arguments.length; i < len; i++) {
      this[this.length] = arguments[i];
      if (Object.prototype.toString.call(this).slice(8, -1).toLowerCase() === 'object') {
        this.length += 1;
      }
    }
    return this.length;
  };
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could add some explanation so the OP can understand better?